# All in one WP Migration won't install asking for localhost login

Tags: wordpress, installation, localhost, backend

Hi I was trying to install the All in one WP Migration to my WordPress but it says I need to login to this interface, what am I going to put on this?

[Trying to log in but getting this error below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzOEA.png)

Answer (score 0):

This form needs an FTP login. It seems like you're using TransIP for hosting. Go to your TransIP control panel of your website, make an FTP account if you don't already have one. And enter the credentials.

I don't know what you're saying with 'asking for localhost login'. 'localhost' is just an alias to point to the same machine. On most machines, this alias points to `127.0.0.1` which directs to itself.